# Creating a BAT file to execute query

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have created a bat file to run a query on our Adaptive Server Anywhere v7 DB.

```
cd C:\LabWorks
dbisqlc -c "DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX" select PONUMBER, orderstatus, writeback, shipdate from orderinfo, shippinginfo where orderinfo.custid < '52467' and orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid; Output to \\Status.csv
```

However it is breaking due to the "<" in the query.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Caret (^) symbol to escape the less than sign. Try:

```
dbisqlc -c "DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX" select PONUMBER, orderstatus, writeback, shipdate from orderinfo, shippinginfo where orderinfo.custid ^< '52467' and orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid; Output to \\Status.csv
```

The caret symbol can also be used to escape other symbols.